# Обход Incapsula

Tags: python, парсер, bs4

Пытаюсь спарсить озон с помощью bs4, но появляется ошибка:

```
Request unsuccessful. Incapsula incident ID: 582000070428219978-1716367462364479949
```

Как я понял, это сработала защита озона от парсинга.
Не подскажите, как ее обойти? Нужно парсить всего около 10 страниц в час.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Поиск тут пробовали по вопросам? Вроде вопросы про Incapsula тут были какие-то уже.